# カラーセットを作ってボタンで切り替えたい

Tags: swift, swiftui

複数のカラーセットを作って、ボタンで一括で切り替えるという仕様にしたいのですが、ボタンの実装の部分で行き詰まっています。

以下のような記述で切り替えられるというのはわかるのですが、App上でボタンの実装の仕方がどうしてもわかりませんでした(View Modeifierを使う？）

```
static let theme = ColorThemeOne()
static let theme = ColorThemeTwo()
```

初心者のため、曖昧な質問で申し訳ないのですが、ご教授いただける方いたら助かります。

**現状のコード:**

```
import SwiftUI

extension Color {
    init(){
        var theme:some View
        self.theme = ColorThemeTwo()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            Color.theme.baseColor
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.theme.circleColor)
                .frame(width:200,height:200)
            Text("Change Color!")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .onTapGesture {
                    //どのように実装したらいいでしょうか
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ColorThemeOne {
    let baseColor = Color(.orange)
    let circleColor = Color(.blue)
    let textColor = Color(.red)
}

struct ColorThemeTwo {
    let baseColor = Color(.purple)
    let circleColor = Color(.green)
    let textColor = Color(.black)    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enumで色の組み合わせ(struct ColorSet)を作ってそれを切り替えていけばうまく変更可能です。

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ColorSet {
  let baseColor: Color
  let circleColor: Color
  let textColor: Color
}

enum ColorMode {
  case first
  case second

  var colorSet: ColorSet {
    switch self {
      case .first:
        return ColorSet(baseColor: .orange, circleColor: .blue, textColor: .red)
      case .second:
        return ColorSet(baseColor: .purple, circleColor: .green, textColor: .black)
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var mode: ColorMode = .first

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      mode.colorSet.baseColor
        .ignoresSafeArea()
      Circle()
        .foregroundColor(mode.colorSet.circleColor)
        .frame(width:200, height:200)
      Text("Change Color!")
        .font(.title)
        .foregroundColor(mode.colorSet.textColor)
        .onTapGesture {
          mode = .second
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。大変助かりました。